# Hice un programa para buscar mails y guardar la respuesta en un excel. El programa funciona un poco, no encuentra todos los correos solo el 30% aprox

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

```
def leer_correos():
    ....
    for num in mensajes[0].split():
        status, msg_data = mail.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
        msg = email.message_from_bytes(msg_data[0][1])     
        asunto = msg['Subject'] 
        ruc_encontrado = extraer_ruc(asunto)                  
        if ruc_encontrado:       
            respuesta = msg.get_payload()            
            wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Programas\Autopartes.xlsx')
            sheet = wb.active
```

Se que debe estar mal programado, es mi primer programa, a alguien se le ocurre como mejorar y hacer que lea todos los mails?
Gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en español. Tu pregunta parece más de revisión de código que de depurar errores como tal. Por favor, lee [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) y no olvides leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Visita también el  [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Pues, la respuesta a tu pregunta depende de donde vienen los mensajes y como los estás extrayendo. Te recomiendo añadir la información relevante a tu pregunta, por ejemplo, un [ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable](/help/minimal-reproducible-example) y, si lees los mensajes desde un archivo, una muestra de dicho archivo (no es necesario que sean datos reales, cualquier cosa que nos de una idea de como "luce" el archivo sirve)

Comment: Tienes un ejemplo concreto con los datos de entrada? es muy difícil ayudarte si no tenemos el código completo.

Comment: Gracias a todos, no podia cargar mas codigo, no me decia que no se puede pegar tanto codigo, gracias a todos. Encontre una pregunta similar que me ayudo a resolver el error

Comment: De nada, lo que te encontraste es un filtro para evitar que pegues mucho código. El punto es reducir ese código (a veces, hasta reescribirlo) para que sea lo más corto posible sin que se pierdan detalles importantes. Esto es para que sea más facil ayudar. De cualquier modo, me alegro de que hayases una solución :D